# Почему в PHP !== возможно, а !=== не бывает?

Tags: php, операторы

Потому, что логическая конструкция `!` работает только с приведенными типами?

Comment: `==` -> `!=`; `===` -> `!==`

Comment: ) Все равно не догоняю, извините, объясните, пожалуйста)

Comment: Есть равно (==), есть неравно (!=)
Есть эквивалентно (===), есть неэквивалентно (!==).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

Немного операторов сравнения в php:

- == - равно
- != - не равно
- === - тождественно равно
- !== - тождественно не равно

То есть, возможно, вы добавляете лишний символ '=', и из-за этого неправильно понимаете оператор.

Comment: Спасибо! Я понял, действительно, лишнее равно писал..

Comment: @Valentin обращайтесь! :)